# Back button changes toolbar layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

This is my Custom Toolbar Layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="217dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/toll_photo" />


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

When I add the back button it changes the toolbar layout it moves it to the left!Help would be appreciated!

I include the toolbar on every activity I need it like this `<include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>`
and on each activity I simply
`<include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>`

```
toolbar= findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back));
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Update this is my style.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

[image]

Comment: By back button you probably think of Up button? https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Comment: @Gotiasits       `toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back));`

Comment: `R.drawable.back` is just the arbitrary name of the graphics, it doesn't say anything about its functionality...

Comment: @Gotiasits you have no idea why it changes my layout why are you commenting?

Comment: I'm trying to get additional info, since your question is not clear enough.

Comment: @Gotiasits you criticised me twice you didn't request anything

Comment: How exactly is that `Toolbar` incorporated into your layout? Also, which part are you talking about when you say "moves it to the left"?

Comment: @MikeM. updated

Comment: Which part moves to the left? Are you saying that your back button isn't where you expect it to be?

Comment: the image is supposed to be centered,and it is in my main activity where there is no back button,when I add it in other fragments it moves to the left @MikeM.

Comment: Oh, you mean the image is shifted to the _right_? It's the default title, which you can't see, because it's the same white color as you've set as the `Toolbar`'s background. Call `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);` after the `setSupportActionBar()` call.

Comment: @MikeM. I am having struggle with this question ,do you mind giving an opinion?https://stackoverflow.com/q/49958847/9635446

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve had the same problem, and despite using the various insets and navigation insets, the result was still not perfect.

I solved it in a *hacky* way, but it works fine and it allowed me to move onto more interesting projects.

My Requirements:

1. Toolbar Dynamic title (I have to update its text because it reads `x of z` where x and z are numbers.
2. Close button *on the right* ( X )
3. Back Button *on some screens*.

With those requirements I set up my layout to *something like this*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"
    tools:parentTag="android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />
</merge>
```

So, for:

1. Now I have a `toolbar_title` textview that I can touch and won’t move regardless of what I do with the toolbar, but will be on top of it, centered.
2. The X is added via a toolbar menu (as usual)
3. The back button, when shown, doesn’t alter the Toolbar, since the text view is flatten on the hierarchy and not controlled by it.

Without back button:

[image: No Back Button]

With back button:

[image: With Back Button]

Notice text stays where I want.

p.s.: I’ve tried to use content inside the toolbar (like you have) and I have been unable to avoid *at least a few pixels* of wiggle when I add/remove icons. LAME.

Comment: does the merge do this trick so for my layout it would be smth like `<merge> <constraint> <toolbar/><image/></contraint></merge>`

Comment: Oh sorry, it depends. I have a merge because I am inflating that layout into another (a matter for another post) but you can replace all the merge with a `ConstraintLayout` (which I have on latest stable version 1.1.0)

Comment: I understand you point ,you are saying that a constraint layout can do the fix?

Comment: What I am saying is that ConstraintLayout, when used that way, gives you a flat hierarchy that allows you to pin a textview exactly centered on your toolbar. It will not move, will correctly grow/shrink horizontally to accommodate for new text and will follow your toolbar around (which, incidentally never moves, so nothing to worry). The only thing to keep in mind is that the text is constrained to the edges of the toolbar (start/end) so there is no natural protection from the text to overlap. There are simple solutions to that if it’s a problem (not for me, since my txt is short).

Comment: A simple solution, is, if icons on the start/end of the text are known, you can add a margin or padding to the textview so it always smaller than the toolbar (since icon sizes are known).

Comment: If you replace _my_ TextView with your imageView, you can make it work.

Comment: true,i worked with just adding a `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);`