# Null Object Reference in RecycleView

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to implement a search filter for my app but I don't know how to do it.I saw a question [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433687/how-to-add-search-filter-for-recyclerview-while-working-with-firestore) but it only made me more confused.This is what I have done this far:
I call the Fragment Class in my main activity like this

```
private JobsFragment jobsFragment=new JobsFragment();
```

Main-Class Activity

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
 final SearchView searchView=(SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {

                 Query querySearch = fb.collection("jobs").whereEqualTo("title", text);
            if (!text.trim().isEmpty()){
                jobsFragment.jobView(querySearch);
            }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (newText.trim().isEmpty()){
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

The RecycleView is in JobsFragment :

```
public void jobView(Query query){

        recycle.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<JobsLists> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<JobsLists>()
                .setQuery(query, JobsLists.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<JobsLists, JobsViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final JobsViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final JobsLists jobsmodel) {

                holder.setTitle(jobsmodel.getTitle());
                holder.setDate(jobsmodel.getDate());
                holder.setCo_Name(jobsmodel.getCo_Name());
                holder.setSkills(jobsmodel.getSkills());
                holder.setLocation(jobsmodel.getLocation());
                holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Context context = v.getContext();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, JobView.class);
                        intent.putExtra("title",  jobsmodel.getTitle());
                        intent.putExtra("skills",  jobsmodel.getSkills());
                        intent.putExtra("company",  jobsmodel.getCo_Name());
                        intent.putExtra("description",  jobsmodel.getDescription());
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public JobsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_card, parent, false);
                return new JobsViewHolder(view);
            }
            @Override
            public int getItemViewType(int position) {

                return position;
            }
        };
        recycle.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Full StackTrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setItemAnimator
(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimator)' on a null object reference
at com.example.dell.ora.JobsFragment.jobView(JobsFragment.java:57)
at com.example.dell.ora.Maino$2.onQueryTextSubmit(Maino.java:71)
at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.onSubmitQuery(SearchView.java:1189)
at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$7.onEditorAction(SearchView.java:1166)
at android.widget.TextView.onEditorAction(TextView.java:5207)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct way in which you can call from an activity a method that exist in a fragment class. You need to use `FragmentManager` like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
    String fragmentTag = fragment.getTag();
    if (fragmentTag != null) {
        String lastCharacter = fragmentTag.substring(fragmentTag.length() - 1);
        if (lastCharacter.equals("0")) {
            JobsFragment jobsFragment = (JobsFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
            jobsFragment.jobView(querySearch);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to insert this inside my ..onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: Exactly. Just do it.

Comment: now it doesnt crush but it doesnt show anything,I click on the icon search and nothing is happening

Comment: Try to add a log statement to see if the method is called. If it is called, it means that the problem is inside your method. Try also to log `fragmentTag` to see if the corresponding TAG of your `JobsFragment` is ending with `0`. It should since is the first fragment that is added.

Comment: `:switcher:2131230925:0
switcher:2131230925:1`

Comment: So the code that i provided you, is correct. In this case the prolem is most likely in your method. Have your tried to use use a log statement to see if is called?

Comment: the method is never called,& I am pretty sure that the method is written wrong anyway.I just copy pasted from the link aboe

Comment: There is a flow. A copy and paste is not enought. You need to do this: find the fragment, create a new adapter for each new character is typed on the search view. If you consider using Firestore, I recomend you see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596610/is-it-possible-to-use-algolia-query-in-firestorerecycleroptions/49607796). The same principle also applies, even if you are not using Firestore and Algolia.

Comment: Is there everything alright?
Have you solved the issue?

Comment: No I haven't Alex,I have started working on another fragment.

Comment: Did my answer helped you in any way?

Comment: Yes,at least now it doesn't crash

Answer (score 0):

You get a null object reference because you're not initializing the `recycle` member, either with direct instantiation in your fragment or with injection (as annotated in the example you linked).

From the example you linked,

```
@BindView(R.id.yourViewId)
RecyclerView recycle;
```

should go in your fragment class.

Otherwise you will have to initialize it by inflating.

Comment: My recycle in the fragment displays correctly when I put a string and click search the app crashes on this line              `jobsFragment.jobView(querySearch);` and then it says a null object how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace as part of your question?

Comment: when you debug, is `jobsFragment` null?

Comment: `private JobsFragment jobsFragment=new JobsFragment();` this is how I call the fragment inside the class which holds this fragment

Comment: I think to add this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/37562572/9635446 in my fragment and then call it inside my class but there are many things that I dont know like `item` Idk what does it refer to

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this:

```
adapter.addFragment(new JobsFragment(), "Jobs");
```

The fragment displayed in the Pager is not the one you're holding onto in the Activity. The one you instantiated as

```
private JobsFragment jobsFragment=new JobsFragment();
```

Actually never got created (i.e. onCreate was never called on it, it's not attached to the activity).

As a direct fix, replace with

```
adapter.addFragment(jobsFragment, "Jobs");
```

But I would suggest to rethink the architecture of the app.

Comment: Hey Dennis can you help me with my new question?

Comment: What new question?

Comment: I'll look into it. But you may want to accept this one if it fixed your issue.

Comment: Dennis its not this one,I have more than 4h with Alex trying to solve it,I would have accepted it as in all my questions

Comment: Well, regardless of other issues you may have with your code, you definitely need to fix this one. I'm pretty sure your NPR is caused by you accessing a "dead" fragment.

Comment: paste . ofcode .org `/i3jsYvpnWv4CpXuDF9bxxs` please take a look

Comment: I'm not sure what you changed. But you're still instantiating two instances of JobsFragment. The one in the member `jobsFragment` is the dead one, i.e. it's `recycle` never gets initialized, because `onCreateView` is never called.